# Paging for dynamic complex queries for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can't find an easy way to make paging for complex queries for SQL server. I need to write function that takes sql query as an argument (this query can include subqueries, order by statements, grouping etc.) and retrieve a particular page of results. In oracle it's easy by encapsulating such query with another select statement, but for SQL server I can't find any simillar way. What I would like to avoid is to parse input SQL statement. I'm using SQL server 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paging in SQL Server 2005 and upwards is best done via ranking functions. However, given that an arbitrary SQL query is unsorted, you need to somehow specify what the sort shall be for this to work, which isn't really "compatible" with a generic solution like you're trying to make (*).

The suggested way to do it is like this (assuming the variables `@PageSize` with the number of items per page, and `@Page` as 1-based index to the page you want to retrieve):

```
WITH NumberedQuery AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.SomeColumn) ix, q.*
  FROM QueryToPage q
)
SELECT nq.*
  FROM NumberedQuery nq
  WHERE (nq.ix >= (@Page-1)*@PageSize) AND (nq.ix < @Page*@PageSize);
```

(*): Your approach with concatenating SQL code has several issues, it prevents the use of parametrized queries, it adds the risk of SQL injection, it hurts performance and it cannot solve the issue at hand if the order is unspecified.